# How to check for available HDF5 options in CMake?

Tags: cmake, hdf5, find-package

I'm using CMake to configure a project including HDF5 support. I can detect whether HDF5 is installed using `find_package(HDF5 ...)`. According to the [CMake manual entry](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindHDF5.html), the `find_package` call will set a few more variables, e.g., `HDF5_IS_PARALLEL`.

However, when building HDF5, one can set a lot more build options. For my project, I need to have an HDF5 installation with both the `HDF5_ENABLE_DIRECT_VFD` and `HDF5_ENABLE_THREADSAFE` options enabled. Trying to run my project using an HDF5 installation without those options will either not compile or yield various runtime errors.

**How can I detect if those options are present in the HDF5 installation during the CMake configuration of my project?**

Answer (score 0):

I found a somewhat working approach: the HDF5 configuration is stored in a file `libhdf5.settings` within the library path. CMake is able to read and parse this file. I have not found a way to reliably get the correct path, though. Still, for the default install directory, this snippet is able to parse the options:

```
find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS C)

if (HDF5_FOUND) 
    message("HDF5 was found, searching configuration...")
    # this search works for default install path of any version
    # change path if hdf5 was build into a non-default directory
    file(GLOB HDF5_SETTINGS "/usr/local/HDF_Group/HDF5/*/lib/libhdf5.settings") 

    if (HDF5_SETTINGS)
        message("Checking HDF5 settings in : ${HDF5_SETTINGS}")
        file(STRINGS ${HDF5_SETTINGS} HDF5_SETTINGS_CONTENT)
        string(REGEX MATCH "Threadsafety: ON" HDF5_HAS_THREADSAFE ${HDF5_SETTINGS_CONTENT})
        string(REGEX MATCH "Direct VFD: 1" HDF5_HAS_DIRECTIO ${HDF5_SETTINGS_CONTENT})
        if (HDF5_HAS_THREADSAFE AND HDF5_HAS_DIRECTIO)
            message("Correct HDF5 settings found.")
        else()
            message(WARNING "HDF5 Settings are incorrect. Please reinstall HDF5 with --threadsafe and --directvfd options enabled.")
            set(HDF5_FOUND false)
        endif()
    endif(HDF5_SETTINGS)
endif(HDF5_FOUND)
```